# redirect folder to specific file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the project folder testproject with both folder and file with same name in root folder. I have product folder and product.html in same root folder which mentioned below.

```
folder structure
 testproject
   product
     edition.html
     integration.html
     security.html
   learn
     learning.html
   product-overview
     integration.html
     security.html 

  .htaccess
  learn.html
  product.html
```

I want to redirect test.testproduct.net/product to test.testproduct.net/product.html

```
Redirect 301 /product/$ http://test.testproduct.net/product.html
```

But it is not redirecting and showing forbidden error.

Comment: You want to redirect `/product` but your redirect states `/product/`?

Comment: need to redirect /product/ folder as product.html.

Comment: You mean you need to do both? Your question and comment are currently saying different things.

Comment: Your .htaccess and other files are inside `testproject`. In that case isn't your final URL as `http://test.synergita.net/testproject/product.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is no 'folder' from the perspective of .htaccess, GET string that is getting parsed. In your case you are working with a string `/product/` but you are forgetting about most people getting used to omitting the last `/` when typing URL to the directory itself.

```
Redirect 301 /product/$ http://test.testproduct.net/product.html
```

The line above will redirect http://test.testproduct.net/product/ to http://test.testproduct.net/product.html

```
Redirect 301 /product$ http://test.testproduct.net/product.html
```

The line above will redirect http://test.testproduct.net/product to http://test.testproduct.net/product.html

Comment: @user3386779 I believe the the latter will not work inside the directory, precisely because there is no slash in the end.